# Pandas apply slow for large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm looking to optimise the below code, which I have working (after much trial and error), but I think can be improved for speed. In reality my dataframes are much larger than the below examples, so I am appealing to the community to help me find a better solution.

I have a dataframe of observational data x and y. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.1,0.12,0.15,0.18,0.20], 'y':[0.08,0.06,0.02,0.07,0.04]})
```

I have a function mapping x to y based on constants a,b,c which I use curve fit to calculate (from a different dataframe of x,y: the fitting is not relevant for this problem). `y=a*exp(-b*x)+c`

I have a dataframe of paramters a, b and c, this is historical data from previous curve fits.

```
hist = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.06,0.067,0.066,0.098,0.10], 'b':[1.8,1.9,1.7,3.2,2.9], 'c':[0.00,0.01,0.005,0.001,0.01]})
```

**The requirement is to filter df based on mean and standard deviaton of y calculated from the historical a,b,c parameters.**

My code below does what is required but becomes slow when run over thousands of rows in 'df', and with hundreds of rows in 'hist'. I made a class to hold the historical data dataframe as there are mulitple seperate categories which I have trivialised for purposes of the example. I feel like there should be a much simpler, faster, more pythonic way to do this, but Im stuck! Thanks for your time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def func(hist_row):
    return hist_row[1] * np.exp(-hist_row[2] * hist_row[0]) + hist_row[3]


class HistData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hist = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.06, 0.067, 0.066, 0.098, 0.10, 0.06, 0.067, 0.066, 0.098, 0.10],
                                  'b': [1.8, 1.9, 1.7, 3.2, 2.9, 1.8, 1.9, 1.7, 3.2, 2.9],
                                  'c': [0.00, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.01, 0.00, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.01],
                                  'category': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']})

    def get_mean_and_std(self, df_row):
        hist = self.hist.loc[self.hist['category'] == df_row[0]].copy()
        hist['x'] = df_row[1]
        hist['y'] = hist[['x', 'a', 'b', 'c']].apply(func, axis=1)
        hist_mean = hist['y'].mean()
        hist_std = hist['y'].std()

        return hist_mean, hist_std


histdata = HistData()

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'x': [0.1, 0.12, 0.15, 0.18, 0.20],
                   'y': [0.08, 0.06, 0.02, 0.07, 0.04]})

df[['hist_mean', 'hist_std']] = df[['category', 'x']].apply(histdata.get_mean_and_std, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df = df.loc[df['y'] < df['hist_mean'] + df['hist_std']]
print(df)
```

Comment: Is it not possible to add a row wise operation like `hist['y']=hist['a'] * np.exp(-hist_row['b'] * hist['x']) + hist['c']` in single line without using apply?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, then I would recommend using multiprocessing Pool to speed up the process. Let me know once you test the first comment and if it doesn't solve your issue, I'll add multiprocessing answer or I'll add a link to other stackoverflow questions

Comment: You have an `apply` within an `apply`, this has to be slow. You can easily vectorize your computation for fast speed.

Comment: many thanks for the responses. I have changed to the row-wise operation and speed is indeed improved